# « merci de me faciliter le passage » contre « merci de faciliter mon passage »

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage, constructions

Sur un autobus j'ai vu le message :

> Je quitte mon arrêt, merci de me faciliter le passage.

Ici, me est-il pronom personnel COI (faciliter à qqun-->il me facilite (le passage)) ou pronom réfléchi (je me facilite (le passage)) ?

Le sens est-il le même avec la phrase ci-dessous ?

> Je quitte mon arrêt, merci de faciliter mon passage.

Alors, pourquoi choisi-t-on la première et non la seconde ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Me* est un complément d'objet indirect. Ce ne peut pas être un pronom réfléchi parce que le sujet n'est pas la même personne que le pronom. Ici le verbe est à l'infinitif à cause de la construction « merci de … », donc le sujet n'est pas explicite. On peut reformuler la proposition avec une autre modalité pour faire apparaître un sujet. Si quelqu'un obéit à la demande, le bus peut dire « quelqu'un me facilite le passage ». Le sujet est le lecteur du panneau, alors que *me* est le bus.

Le pronom *me* pourrait être un COD ou un COI. Un locuteur natif peut voir facilement lequel c'est en passant à la troisième personne : le bus demande de *lui* faciliter le passage. C'est un COI : *lui* est le pronom COI à la troisième personne du singulier ; la forme du COD est *le*.

Pour faire mieux apparaître la construction grammaticale, il faudrait remplacer le pronom par son antécédent. Cela donne « merci de faciliter le passage au bus ». Le COI est introduit par la préposition *à* (et *à + le* se contracte en *au*). Mais attention, cette phrase n'est pas vraiment idiomatique ! On dirait plutôt « merci de faciliter le passage du bus ».

Il y a deux manière de construire la phrase qui sont synonymes :

- « faciliter (le X de Y) » : verbe + COD, le COD a un complément de nom. Si l'on veut remplacer Y par un pronom, cela devient « faciliter AP X » où AP est l'adjectif possessif correspondant (*mon*, *ton*, …).
- « faciliter (le X) (à Y) » : verbe + COD + COI.

En règle générale, on préfère la forme avec COI quand Y est un pronom, et la forme avec complément de nom quand Y n'est pas un pronom.

> « ***lui faciliter le passage*** »   (*faciliter son passage* est possible mais moins courant et est du langage soutenu)
>   « ***faciliter le passage du bus*** »   (*faciliter le passage au bus* est possible mais moins courant et rare en dehors du langage familier)

Cette dualité de construction est très générale, on peut la retrouver avec de très nombreux verbes. Par exemple :

> « Le chirurgien opère la jambe du patient. »   (plus rare, familier : « Le chirurgien opère la jambe au patient. »)
>   « Le chirurgien lui opère la jambe. »   (plus rare, soutenu : « Le chirurgien opère sa jambe. »)

Penser à un pronom réfléchi dans la phrase de la question n'était pas complètement hors de propos, parce que c'est une construction qu'on retrouve avec un pronom réfléchi dans beaucoup d'expressions courantes telles que « je me lave les mains », « il s'est cassé le bras », etc. Dans beaucoup d'autres langues on utiliserait la structure « *<s>je lave mes mains</s> », « *<s>il a cassé son bras</s> » mais ces constructions ne sont pas du tout idiomatiques en français (même en langage soutenu).

Il y a une légère nuance entre les deux constructions. Après tout, il n'y a pas de synonyme parfait. « Verbe + le X de Y » groupe l'objet X avec la personne Y et considère le verbe comme une action séparée. « Verbe + le X + à Y » considère « verbe + le X » comme une action qui arrive à Y. Il y a quelques cas où une des constructions ne marche pas. Si « verbe + le X » est une expression idiomatique, il est fréquent qu'elle n'ait ce sens que lorsque le COD est exactement « le X », et pas lorsque c'est « le X de Y ». Par exemple, « il [tient la jambe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenir_la_jambe) à sa sœur » signifie qu'il lui parle pendant très longtemps (sens figuré), alors que « il tient la jambe de sa sœur » signifie qu'il porte sa jambe entre ses mains (sens propre). (Dans cet exemple, « il lui tient la jambe » a en général le sens figuré, mais peut avoir le sens propre si le contexte rend clair que c'est le sens propre — « il lui tient la jambe pour l'aider à escalader le mur ».)

Mais dans la plupart des cas, les deux constructions ont exactement le même sens, et on utilise plutôt le COI quand c'est un pronom et plutôt un complément de nom lorsque c'est un nom. Dans le cas du bus, « merci de faciliter mon passage » et « merci de me faciliter le passage » ont exactement le même sens. Les deux sont idiomatiques en langage soutenu mais « me faciliter le passage » est un peu plus courant, et on ne dirait pas « faciliter mon passage » en langage familier.

Answer (score 1):

Le sens n'est pas exactement le même. "Mon passage" implique que la personne s'approprie le passage alors que ce n'est pas le cas dans la première formulation. Dans la première formulation, la personne demande une interaction avec elle-même alors que dans la deuxième, elle demande une interaction avec le passage qu'elle s'approprie (mon passage). Je ne sais pas si ma réponse est claire.

Lorsque l'on utilise le pronom "mon" cela implique une possession, sommes-nous d'accord sur cela? En disant "mon passage", cela implique la possession. Ce qui n'est pas le cas avec la formulation initiale. La personne demande qu'on lui facilite le passage de manière générale, le passage que tout le monde emprunte, qui n'appartient à personne en particulier. Donc ce point de vu déjà les deux formules ne peuvent pas avoir le même sens, même si cela semble etre le cas.

**EDIT suite à mon erreur ayant reçu la réponse d'un professeur de français :**

**Me** est un pronom qui ne peut avoir un sujet. Il remplace  le sujet **je** de la première proposition et il est **COI** du verbe faciliter dont le **COD** est passage.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78216/discussion-on-answer-by-franck-gamess-deux-phrases-faciliter-vs-me-faciliter-c).

Comment: Non, « mon passage » n'implique pas que la personne s'approprie le passage. Ici, le passage, c'est la possibilité de passer. Le pronom *mon* n'implique pas du tout une possession, il est beaucoup plus général que cela (par exemple, quand on dit « mon amour » ou « mes parents », il n'y a clairement pas du tout de possession). Les deux constructions ont exactement le même sens.

Comment: @Gilles: je vois une nuance aussi. *Merci de facilliter mon passage* c'est plus autoritaire. C'est, je dirais, un rappel à la règle. Je me vois mal dire ça dans la rue, par exemple, sauf si il y a une vraie raison à ce que mon passage soit prioritaire. Dans *merci de me*, le seul fait qu'il ait un pronom objet change cela en un remerciement un peu plus sincère pour courtoisie rendue.